# How to make combo box searchable in access?

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

[PICTURE OF COMBO BOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACB52.png)

I have included a picture above.
I have an access form that I created and I am using a combo box with a list of names that I would like a user to select. How can I make the combo box searchable so that a user would just have to type in the beginning of a name and it would come up with the closest name in the list, as opposed to having to scroll ALL the way to the bottom for a name that begins with a "w" for example. 
Any help would be awesome! thanks in advance :)